# Nodejs mysql pool error cannot call method query of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

tried to do a mysql pooling but I get stuck on the connection.query part.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var pool  =  mysql.createPool({
  host      : 'localhost',
  user      : 'asdf',
  password  : 'asdf',
  database  : 'cr',
  connectionLimit : 100
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        connection.query("select * from configuration where client_id =" + request.user,function(err,rows){ 
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                response.json(rows);
            }   

        });
        connection.on('error', function(err) {      
              response.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Unable to connect"});
              return;     
        });

        connection.release();
    });
});
```

It seems to be stopping at connection.query as connection appears null, how do i rectify this?

Comment: Does the `err` object (in `pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){`) contain a value that might explain why the `connection` is null?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you restructure your code for better debugging so that *you* can find out why `connection` appears to be null in your `pool.getConnection` callback function.

Generally it is good practice within a callback function to verify that you get a valid response before processing that response.

In your case, checking for an `err` is a first step. You should also check for the existence of `connection` and optionally its properties like `query`. I recommend the following to debug your issue:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) { 
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (connection && 'query' in connection) {
    // process connection and connection.query
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from this snippet, but the initial SQL select (`select * from configuration where client_id =`) is expecting the `request` to have a `request.user` set....but nowhere in your express routing is it clear that `request.user` is being set.  If `request.user` is as empty as it seems, the resulting SQL would be invalid, almost certainly causing the error.